# Why won't what the user clicked appear on my modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

My code was a bit messy before in terms of having a method for each kind of food and using each of those methods to display which type of food the user selected upon clicking which ever `</FoodButton>` the user desires.

Now, I want to optimize it in a way where it's only one method that handles it all.

There error I'm getting says:

```
'item' is not defined
```

(referring to `<FoodButton clicked={() => this.selectItem(item)} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>`)

I've been trying so many different ways of fixing this but can't seem to find a solution.

How come what I'm doing isn't working?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import FoodButton from '../FoodButtons/FoodButton';
import CheckoutButton from '../CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton';
import axios from '../../../../axios-foodChosen';

import { CLOSE_MODAL, OPEN_MODAL } from "../../../../store/action/NoNameAction";

class TacoTypes extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedItem: ''
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.items = {
            chickenTaco: 'Chicken Taco',
            beefTaco: 'Beef Taco',
            chickenBurrito: 'Chicken Burrito'
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // for modal
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

    selectItem(item) {
        this.setState({selectedItem: item})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.selectItem(item)} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.beefTaco()} label={"Beef Taco"}/>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.chickenBurrito()} label={"Chicken Burrito"}/>

                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                    <p>
                        {this.items.map(item => (
                            <p key={item}>{item}</p>
                        ))}
                    </p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        // props for modal
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        // Modal handlers
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: OPEN_MODAL}),
        closeModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TacoTypes);
```

Comment: Well, `item` isn't defined, as it says. What should it be? (There's no mention of a variable called `item` anywhere in your code, aside from the parameter in `selectItem`.)

Comment: @AKX yeah I know that, but besides that error, is everything else correct in terms of the logic?

Comment: Well, no... There's nothing in the `Modal` that would read your `state`, either.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Redux fluff for the time being, this should work:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";

import FoodButton from "../FoodButtons/FoodButton";
import CheckoutButton from "../CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton";

class TacoTypes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: undefined,
      modalIsOpen: false,
    };
    this.items = {
      chickenTaco: "Chicken Taco",
      beefTaco: "Beef Taco",
      chickenBurrito: "Chicken Burrito",
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Modal.setAppElement("body");
  }

  selectItem(item) {
    this.setState({ selectedItem: item });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
        {Object.entries(this.items).map(([item, label]) => (
          <FoodButton
            clicked={() => this.selectItem.call(this, item)}
            label={label}
            key={item}
          />
        ))}

        <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true })} />

        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}>
          <p>
            {Object.entries(this.items).map(([item, label]) => (
              <p key={item}>
                {item}
                {this.state.selectedItem === item
                  ? " (You chose this one!)"
                  : null}
              </p>
            ))}
          </p>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false })}>
            Close
          </button>
        </Modal>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}
```

(I'm using `this.selectItem.call(this, ...)`) because I'm not sure if your environment is set up for functions as class properties. If it is, you can do

```
selectItem = (item) => {
  this.setState({ selectedItem: item });
}

// ...

clicked={() => this.selectItem(item)}
```

instead.
)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the variable `item` is not defined. This should work:

```
<FoodButton clicked={() => this.selectItem('Chicken Taco')} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>
```

Or

```
<FoodButton clicked={() => this.selectItem(this.items.chickenTaco)} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>
```

**UPDATE:**

> I want to display in the modal only the buttons that user clicked on

There are multiple ways to do that depending on how you arrange your data. I'll show one option here as a proof of concept:

There are three buttons. Click on either one of them will add corresponding item to the selected list (or remove from the list if it is already selected). You might do something similar in your specific setup.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: {
        chicken: false,
        beef: false,
        other: false
      }
    }
  }
  onSelect (name) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        items: {
          ...prevState.items,
          [name]: !prevState.items[name]
        }
      }
    })
  }
  getSelected () {
    return Object.entries(this.state.items).filter(entry => entry[1]).map(entry => entry[0]).join(',')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {Object.keys(this.state.items).map(name => (
        <button onClick={() => this.onSelect(name)} key={name}>{name}</button>
      ))}
      
      <div> 
        Selected: {this.getSelected()}
      </div>
      
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: ah ok!  This works.  But what if I want more than one type of food to display.  Right now, it only displays the first button clicked but not when first and second button are clicked (yes, I did `<FoodButton clicked={() => this.selectItem('Food Name')} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>` on the other buttons as well.

Comment: @sp92 so you want to be able to select multiple items and display all the selected items somewhere (maybe in the modal)? Then you might need to change `state.selectedItem` to be an array instead of a single item

Comment: yes correct.  I want to display in the modal only the buttons that user clicked on.  How would I do that?  I've been hacking away for hours but can't come up with anything :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `item` you need to specify it as a function parameter:

`<FoodButton clicked={item => this.selectItem(item)} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>`